# Is there something like the OWASP top 10 for BizTalk applications?

Tags: biztalk

I'm familiar with the OWASP top 10, for web applications. Is there something simular for BizTalk applications?

Comment: All standard secure coding principles apply. There is not a handy Top 10 list for specific vendor frameworks.

Comment: We tried to edit it to make it more general, and hence, on topic, but you rejected the edit. As such, it is closed again.

Comment: To the OP - The reason I edited the question is that it's off-topic as it stands.   We don't want to propagate repetitive "OWASP for [specific application type]" questions.

Comment: @Xander If this kind of question is not desired as-is, then please close / delete it, but don't edit it to be something it is not intended to be. The accepted answer is specific for BizTalk as well, so when changing the question you would need to change the answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OWASP Top 10 is not language specific; it is applicable for all web applications.  The [CWE Top 25](http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/) is the most generally used list for non-web applications. That's probably what you're looking for.

If you want something language specific, it'd be most helpful to look for a biztalk security guidance or a BizTalk hardening guide and also to obey common practices like treating all user input as malicious.

Comment: Great recommendation! Also check out SAFEcode -- http://safecode.org